# como puedo pasar este algoritmo a python, he intentado pero aún no me sale de manera correcta

Tags: python-3.7

Escribir "producto y suma entre dos numeros naturales"

```
Escribir "ingrese primer numero"
Leer n1
Escribir "ingrese segundo numero"
leer n2
pn=0;
sn=1;
i=n1+1;
Si n1>n2 Entonces
    Para j=n1-1 Hasta n2+1 Con Paso -1 Hacer
        Escribir j
        sn=sn+j;
    Fin Para
    Escribir "EL PRODUCTO DE LOS NUMEROS ES ", sn;
Sino
    Mientras i<n2 Hacer
        Escribir i
        pn=pn+i;
        i=i+1;
    Fin mientras 
    Escribir "LA SUMA DE LOS NUMEROS ES ", pn;
        
FinSi
```

Este es el código a Python que generado a partir del algoritmo anterior para producto y suma entre dos números naturales, pero que aun no me sale de manera correcta:

```
print("producto y suma entre dos numeros naturales") 
print("ingrese primer numero") 
n1 = float(input()) 
print("ingrese segundo numero") 
n2 = float(input()) 
pn = 0 
sn = 1 
i = n1+1 
if n1>n2:
    for j in range(n1-1,n2,-1): 
        print (j) 
        sn = sn+j 
    print("EL PRODUCTO DE LOS NUMEROS ES ",sn) 
else: 
    while i<n2: 
        print(i) 
        pn = pn+i 
        i = i+1 
    print("LA SUMA DE LOS NUMEROS ES ",pn)
```

obtengo el suguiente error:

```
producto y suma entre dos numeros naturales
ingrese primer numero
6
ingrese segundo numero
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 12, in 
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: "... He intentado..."... Podrias agregar tu intento para demostrar tu afirmacion por favor? Asi evitaras dar la impresion de que queres que te hagan la tarea y por lo tanto tambien evitaras el cierre de la pregunta y la falta de respuestas.

Comment: print("producto y suma entre dos numeros naturales")
print("ingrese primer numero")
n1 = float(input())
print("ingrese segundo numero")
n2 = float(input())
pn = 0
sn = 1
i = n1+1
if n1>n2:
  for j in range(n1-1,n2,-1):
  print (j):
sn = sn+j
print("EL PRODUCTO DE LOS NUMEROS ES ",sn)
else:
while i<n2:
print(i)
pn = pn+i
i = i+1
print("LA SUMA DE LOS NUMEROS ES ",pn)

Comment: Gracias! Pero como habras notado, el código no se ve bien en los comentarios. Podrias editar la pregunta y ponerlo alli por favor?

Comment: Que resultado esperas? pon un ejemplo. Porque el algoritmo parece tener trampa y no hace lo que te dicen que debe hacer...no suma ni multiplica, hace sumatorios de un rango

Answer (score 0):

La función `range()` solo admite números enteros, en tu caso pusiste un número decimal el cual es el `float`, que escribiste en:

```
n1=float(input())
```

Si querías que tu función range hiciera su función, debiste haber convertido `n1` a un entero

```
n1=int(n1)
```

y ya puedes usarlo en la función `range`

Comment: Dudo que la persona que preguntó te responda si le fue útil o no, si observas borró su cuenta

Comment: no me di cuenta es que soy nuevo por aqui en este sitio,se programar desde hace mucho tiempo pero no sabia qie esto existia y me parecio interesante,perdon si hice alguna estupidez

Comment: Nadie dijo que hicieras algo así, lo que te comenté es para que no esperes de momento en vano que quien preguntó te responda, ya que eliminó su cuenta

Comment: Basta con [edit] tu respuesta y eliminar la pregunta en donde estás pidiendo feedback (en este caso fue "¿te fue útil?"). No pidas aclaraciones (ni dejes saludos ni agradecimientos) en las respuestas. Lee [answer]  y haz (de nuevo) el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score -2):

La función *range* no funciona con números decimales.
Para controlar que el numero introducido es un numero natural(entero y positivo):

```
while True:
            print("ingrese primer numero") 
            try:
              num = float(input())
              if(num>0 and int(num)==num): break
              else:
                  print ("ATENCIÓN: Debe ingresar un entero mayor que cero o positivo")
             
            except ValueError:
                print ("ATENCIÓN: Debe ingresar un valor númerico entero")
n1=int(num)
```

Comment: El algortimo planteado en la pregunta contiene una iteración *Para j=n1-1 Hasta n2+1* que no aparece en la respuesta.

Comment: Lo se, es que no quería dar toda la solución porque en otras preguntas me ha dicho que no lo haga cuando no se han trabajado la pregunta.

Comment: En realidad, no esta bueno ir contestando preguntas de baja calidad. Fomentas que aparezcan aun mas preguntas de baja calidad. Quiza los que dijeron eso se referian a ello.

Comment: Yo no se quien determina la calidad de las preguntas, entiendo a lo que te refieres. Pero a mi en particular esta me pareció interesante. Como profesional nunca me han planteado un problema con calidad